# What is the term for this expression r = (1 if v in c.values() else 0)

Tags: python-3.x, function, counter

Is there a specific term/name for this expression `r = (1 if v in c.values() else 0)` in computer science?

```
def Query(queries):
    from collections import Counter

    c=Counter()
    result=[]

    for k,v in queries:
        if k==1:
            c[v]+=1


        elif k==2 and v in c:
            c[v]-=1

        elif k==3:

            r = (1 if v in c.values() else 0)
            result+=[r]

    return result
```

Comment: ternary or conditional expression?

Comment: @sacul yes - but to be clear, conditional expression is a subset (kind of) ternary expression.  "ternary" just means that there are technically 3 operands, same as in C's `?:`

Answer (score 3):

Python distinguishes *expressions*, which evaluate to a value, from *statements* (instructions), which do not. Any expression can be used as a statement in Python (as an expression statement) in which case the value is simply discarded. Other types of statements may contain expressions, and expressions may contain subexpressions.

`r = (1 if v in c.values() else 0)` is not an expression, nor even an expression statement. It is an *assignment statement*.

On its right-hand side, this assignment statement contains a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) `(1 if v in c.values() else 0)`, containing three subexpressions,

- a [Comparison](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) expression `v in c.values()`,
- a [literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#literals) integer `1`, and
- a literal integer `0`.

Comparisons evaluate to a bool and have more complex evaluation rules than simple arithmetic operators, because they can be chained. This comparison only uses a single operator, `in`, and contains two subexpressions,

- an [identifier](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers) atom  `v`, and
- one comparator, a call: `c.values()`.

The call expression contains an *attribute reference* [primary](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#primaries) `c.values`. This is considered a subexpression of the call expression.

You can see exactly how Python parses this by using the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module.

```
>>> import ast
>>> print(ast.dump(compile('r = (1 if v in c.values() else 0)', '<str>', 'exec', ast.PyCF_ONLY_AST)))
Module(body=[Assign(targets=[Name(id='r', ctx=Store())], value=IfExp(test=Compare(left=Name(id='v', ctx=Load()), ops=[In()], comparators=[Call(func=Attribute(value=Name(id='c', ctx=Load()), attr='values', ctx=Load()), args=[], keywords=[])]), body=Num(n=1), orelse=Num(n=0)))])
```

This is a little hard to read on one line. Here it is reformatted. I've also stripped away the module wrapper created by the compilation, which is not relevant to this discussion.

```
Assign(
    targets=[Name(id="r", ctx=Store())],
    value=IfExp(
        test=Compare(
            left=Name(id="v", ctx=Load()),
            ops=[In()],
            comparators=[
                Call(
                    func=Attribute(
                        value=Name(id="c", ctx=Load()), attr="values", ctx=Load()
                    ),
                    args=[],
                    keywords=[],
                )
            ],
        ),
        body=Num(n=1),
        orelse=Num(n=0),
    ),
)
```